# the purpose of locale-gen and localization files

Tags: locale

From around stack exchange:

> ```
> Compiled locale files take about 50MB of disk space.
> ```

Well, I thought that locales simply advise programs on what language or time format to use, but 50MB is a lot of data. What information is stored in these localization files generated by locale-gen? Common translations? Culinary recipes?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you found that quote? Also, 50MB is nothing in these days, unless you operate on a micro-controller, but you would not install a full Ubuntu system there anyway. I'd not worry about it.

Comment: As a start, you might read `man locale-gen`.

Comment: It seems the quote comes directly from the man page, but little more is written there about the purpose of these files.

Answer (score 1):

The locale definition files, with the information in cleartext (well, sort of...), are located in the `/usr/share/i18n/locales` folder. The compiled locale data is stored in the `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` file, which is normally far smaller than 50 MB. To see which locales are currently compiled you can run:

```
locale -a
```